# What's the standard notation for the differential of $f:M\rightarrow N$?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

What's the standard notation for the differential of a function $f:M\rightarrow N$ between manifolds?

If $N=\mathbb{R}$, it's written $df:TM\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}$. Is this used for multidimensional case?

Comment: I am not sure that somebody would actually write $df:TM\to \mathbb{R}$ when $N=\mathbb{R}$.  $T\mathbb{R}$ is actually $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, so unless that person means $d_pf:T_pM\to \mathbb{R}$, I think the notation $df:TM\to\mathbb{R}$ is meaningless.

Comment: @Zvi It was a mistake. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen:

- $df$
- $Df$
- $J_f$
- $\operatorname{Jac}(f)$
- Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion
- $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ (in coordinates)
- C-beams glitter in the dark near Tannhäuser Gate

What I use depends on context. If I'm thinking in coordinate-free terms, I like $df$. If I'm thinking in terms of coordinates, I like "$J_f$" to emphasize that this is a Jacobian matrix of $f$.

Comment: All these and no $f_\ast$ !

Comment: So sad all that notation will be lost in time.

Answer (score 2):

I would write $Tf : TM \to TN$ which is a morphism of vector bundles. This makes transparent that we get a functor $T$ from the category of smooth manifolds and smooth 
maps to the category of smooth vector bundles over smooth manifolds and smooth bundle morphisms.

$Tf$ may be considered as the collection of linear maps $T_p f : T_p M \to T_f(p) N$, $p \in M$.

If the tangent bundle $TN$ is trivial (that is, there exists a smooth bundle isomorphism $h : TN \to N \times \mathbb{R}^n$), you can "identify" $Tf$ with the smooth map

$$T^h f : TM \stackrel{Tf}{\rightarrow} TN \stackrel{h}{\rightarrow} N \times \mathbb{R}^n \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}^n .$$

In fact, $Tf$ can be recovered from $T^h f$ via $T_p f = h_{f(p)}^{-1} \circ T^h_p f$. Note however, that $h$ is not uniquely determined, so $T^h f$ involves a *choice*. In case $N = \mathbb{R}$ there is a canonical choice.

Comment: While I sort of agree, the claim that we "get a functor from ... to ..." isn't so obvious to me; OP said nothing about smoothness, and indeed, the manifolds and maps in the question might be only known to be $C^1$. Also...while I like the $Tf$ notation, the fact that Milnor and Stasheff don't (consistently) use it makes me think that other choices might be just as good, so "You should" might be a little too strong. [Also: OP asked what the standard was (presuming it exists), not what the ideal was, so in some sense this doesn't address the question.]

Comment: @JohnHughes Concerning the "You should" part I agree and edit my answer. In the $C^k$-case you also get a functor, but other categories are involved.

Comment: Indeed -- that was sort of my point: merely giving the differential a name that starts with the same letter doesn't tell you nearly as much as your answer suggested (to me at least), although I agree that it helps to remind use that it is *some* kind of functor.

Comment: @JohnHughes I see your point. In fact, saying that $T$ is a functor (living on whatever category) may be regarded as a pretentious way of formulating the chain rule  ;-) However, I believe that using homogeneous notation is never a disadvantage.

Comment: +1 for the amusing notion of formulating the chain rule so that it can only be understood by those who already understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a discussion:

If $M$ and $N$ are two smooth manifolds and $f:M\rightarrow N$ is differentiable at $p\in M$ then the differential map is denoted and defined as $D_pf:T_pM\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$, where $T_pM$ and $T_{f(p)}N$ are the tangent spaces at $p$ and $f(p)$ of $M$ and $N$ respectively.